# Lenovo Thinkpad T500 won't hold charge, brand new battery

Tags: windows-10, thinkpad, lenovo-laptop

I replaced the battery in my old Lenovo Thinkpad T500, but it is still dying after sitting for a few hours. OS is Win10 Pro. Even if I set the laptop to Hibernate, the battery still somehow dies. Any ideas how I can fix this? Thanks.

EDIT: The laptop dual-boots to Kali Linux, so I will try letting it sleep under the Linux OS to see if the battery still dies. I am thinking it is a Windows 10 issue that is killing that battery.

EDIT2: The computer is not going to sleep or hibernating when I close the lid.

Comment: Get it serviced.

Comment: David, I'm an computer technician myself, I can fix it. I just need a bit of guidance and some other ideas.

Comment: That doesn't make you a hardware diagnosis and repair specialist.

Comment: ...also, this laptop is quite old, so it would instantly be "totaled" (not cost-effective to fix) if I were to take it to a shop for service.

Comment: @DavidPostill, right. So can you offer anything helpful at all...or no?

Comment: @SamAndrew81 BIOS updated actually make a huge difference for thinkpads.

Comment: Thanks, @user2497. I updated the BIOS, but there's no change.

Answer (score 2):

Boot to linux, and issue `upower -d`. It will report directly original and current capacity of the battery. Try halting the machine, removing the battery, and pressing power to drain the system. Then start again. A thinkpad will not necessarily discover a new battery's capacity (if greater or smaller than the old one's), without a few whacks and boots.